# C++ executable file error in Sun Solaris 11

Tags: c++, solaris

When i run the C++ executable file in the Sun Solaris 11 getting the below errror.

ld.so.1: tpbga: fatal: relocation error: file tpbga: symbol __1cNOutputHandlerMsdTraceLevel_: referenced symbol not found

Same is working in Sun Solaris 10.

Please help.

Comment: Wow - I didn't know anybody was still using Solaris.  SUGGESTION: run "ldd" on both executables, and see if there's any missing shared libraries.

Answer (score 0):

`OutputHandlerMsdTraceLevel` is not part of any Solaris or mainstream C++ library I'm aware of.

Your `tpbga` binary is likely dynamically linked with a shared library that you failed to install on the Solaris 11 machine but present on the Solaris 10 one.

As FoggyDay already stated, `ldd tpbga` or `ldd $(which tpbga)` will tell you which library is missing on the former and where it is located in the latter.